# Returning a pointer to the array passed to parameter list

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to return a pointer to the array I just passed. Why am I not allowed to?

```
int(*func(int arr[10]))[10]
{
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you pass an array to a function, it decays to a *pointer*, more precisely to a pointer to the first element.

In your example, the argument `arr` is actually a *pointer* and not an array (which is also why you can't use `sizeof` on the "array", that gets the size of the pointer and not what it points to). When you declare an argument such as `int arr[X]` (the value of `X` doesn't matter) it's actually equivalent to declaring `int *arr`. When you know that it's also very clear what the actual return type should have been: `int*`:

```
int* func(int* arr)
{
    return arr;
}
```

One way to remove doubt or ambiguities would have been to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
std::array<int, 10>& func(std::array<int, 10>& arr)
{
    return arr;
}
```

---

As a side-note, if you hade an *actual* array of integers, say

```
int arr[10] = { ... };
```

then to get a pointer to that (which would be of type `int (*)[10]`) then you would have to use the address-of operator as usual:

```
&arr;
```

---

Regarding your comment, lets say you had a `static` array inside the function, and what to return an actual *pointer* to the array, then you would have to use that "weird" return-type syntax.

```
int (*func(int x))[10]
{
    static int arr[10] = { ... };  // Define and initialize array
    // Some other code...
    return &arr;  // Return a POINTER to the array
}
```

In the function above, the type of `arr` is `int[10]`. A *pointer* to the array, which is what you get when you use `&arr`, is of type `int(*)[10]`.

Now expanding this type as a return type to a function we get `int (*func(...))[10]`.

As above, using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) would have made it clearer (IMO).

Comment: The OP isn't calling the function. Her problem is about function declarations, not about function calls.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was coming to that... :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Im reading a C++ Primer and i actually rereading a part about functions returning pointers to arrays and functions. There is an example of a function returning a pointer to an array with the declaration like this: `int (*func(int a))[10]`. Why do i need to state a returning array size if i can just return an array as you adviced?

Comment: @vdublevsky Updated my answer in regards to your comment. The important thing to know here is that an array decaying to a pointer is not the same as a pointer to the array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you! Seems like i need to do some research on array decaying to a pointer vs a pointer to array

Comment: @vdublevsky I just wrote [this simple and brief explanation](https://ghost.pileborg.se/2016/08/28/the-difference-between-arrays-decaying-to-pointers-and-pointers-to-arrays/) about the difference between array decaying to pointer to its first element, and a pointer to an array.